# How to change a sklabelnode into a nsinteger

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

How can i properly change the following into a NSInteger:

```
countDown.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", (int)(currentTime-startTime)];
```

Countdown is a SKLabelnode

Answer (score 0):

There's no real benefit to casting to an `NSInteger` (which is just a `typedef` for `long` on 64-bit architectures and `int` on 32-bit architectures) , but you can do that by changing your code into the following:

```
countDown.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (NSInteger)(currentTime-startTime)];
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `NSNumberFormatter`

For example:

```
NSString *string = @"12";
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSInteger i = [[formatter numberFromString:string] integerValue];
```

Comment: Creating an `NSFormatter` instance each time an integer is to be formatted is enormously expensive. Make sure to cache an instance for repeated use if you go this route.

Comment: Yeah, like that idea better

Comment: @pulsar what do i put in place of 12?

Comment: You would put `countDown.text` where `@"12"` is but consider what @mattt is saying. If you're going to be doing this a lot then make a property to hold an `NSInteger` and set it when you set your `countDown.text`.